# Destructuring object in array on next js backend

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

How can I resolve this? I put req.query parameter with an array but I can't destructure or use items from my array. I getting on my next.js API backend just [object Object] or undefined. How can I select what I want?

```
const fetchData = async (queryKey: any, manufacturer) => {
  const res = await fetch(
    `http://localhost:3000/api/data/get?&manufacturer=${manufacturers}`
  );
  return await res.json();
};

const manufacturers = [
  { name: 'Samsung', type: 'TV' },
  { name: 'Nokia', type: 'Phone' },
];

const { data, status } = useQuery(
   ['somekey', manufacturer],
   ({ queryKey }) => fetchData(queryKey, manufacturer)
);
```

And here is the next API where I can't get values from the query I getting just
[Object, Object] or undefined,

this code work if just put on the front end just a simple array or string without an object in variable manufacturers.

But how i can get values from [Object, object]?
I try it

```
const { name, type } = req.query.manufacturer
const { name, type } = req.query.manufacturer[0]
```

or select just one field dont work to = const some = req.query.manufacturer[0].name

```
export const handler = async (
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse<Data>
) => {
  const { name, type } = req.query.manufacturer;
};

export default handler;
```

Comment: You can't pass arrays/objects in query parameters like that, the value needs to be a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try `const [{ name, type }] = req.query.manufacturer`? Seems to be what you need

**edit**

Also, you may want to try instead of `http://localhost:3000/api/data/get?&manufacturer=${manufacturers}` => `http://localhost:3000/api/data/get?&manufacturer=${encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(manufacturers))}`

It probably will be accessible with `{ name, type } = req.query.manufacturer` then

Comment: Thanks try it, wont work :-(   undefined undefined and ts error  "Type 'string' is not an array type or a string type. Use compiler option '--downlevelIteration' to allow iterating of iterators"

Comment: Maybe const [{ name, type }] = JSON.parse(req.query.manufacturer)? What's console.log(req.query.manufacturer) prints anyways? : )

Comment: console.log(req.query.manufacturer) prints  [object Object]  ön  console.log(JSON.parse(req.query.manufacturer)) error - SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1 ..... Whole problem is because i need put some dynamic data for filtering in Prisma (WHERE) for a ecommerce website. If i just put data in query parameters manualy like ?size="xl"&manufacturer="samsung"&color="black" and then destructuring works. But each page category have different filter parameters and i need pass dynamically this data to query parameter :-) :-(

Comment: It seems that your req.query.manufacturer is literally a string `"[object Object]"`

Comment: You may want to try instead of `http://localhost:3000/api/data/get?&manufacturer=${manufacturers}` => `http://localhost:3000/api/data/get?&manufacturer=${encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(manufacturers))}`

It probably will be accessible with `{ name, type } = req.query.manufacturer` then

Comment: Thanks again Igor, work with econdeURI :-) ...  Just on backend i add it 
  const myData = JSON.parse(req.query.manufacturer) and then i can destruct  const { name, type } = myData[0]  ... Just  last thingTypeScript its not happy with req.query.manufacturer  "Argument of type 'string | string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2345)"

Comment: You could cast it `req.query.manufacturer as string`